# Prove $f:\mathbb{R}^2\to B(0,1)$ s.t. $f(x)=x/(1+||x||)$ is continuous

Tags: general-topology, continuity

I am trying to prove that

> $$\begin{align}f:\mathbb{R}^2&\to B(0,1)\\ f(x)&=\frac{x}{(1+||x||)}\end{align}$$
> is a homeomorphism between $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $B(0,1)$.

I have proved that $f$ is bijective, but got stuck in proving that it is continuous. I am trying to use the theory that $f$ is continuous if and only if for every basis element $B$ of $B (0,1)$, $f^{-1}(B)$ is open in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Any suggestion would be helpful. Thank you.

Comment: It depends on what kinds of tools you have, but you could argue that the scalar-valued function $\alpha(x) = \frac{1}{\|x\| + 1}$ is continuous, and that $\alpha(x)x$ is continuous as a product of a continuous scalar function and a continuous vector function.

Answer (score 1):

The easy way is in the comments.  Inverse image of basic set isn't too hard,  take a $B(y,\epsilon)$ where $y$ is in your open sphere,  there is a preimage $x$ of $y$,  so $y=\frac x {1 + \|x\|}$.  A point within some $\delta$ of $x$ can be written as $x+\delta v$,  where $v$ is a unit vector showing the direction from $x$.  $$f(x+\delta v)=\frac {x + \delta v}{1 +\|x+\delta v\|}$$.  We just need to bound $\delta$ so that the difference between $f(x)$ and $f(x+\delta v$) is less than $\epsilon$.

$$\|f(x+\delta v)-f(x)\|=\left\|\frac {x + \delta v}{1 +\|x+\delta v\|}-\frac x {1 + \|x\|}\right\|=\left\| \frac {(1+\|x\|)(x+\delta v)-(1+\|x+\delta v\|)x}{(1 +\|x+\delta v\|)(1+\|x\|)}\right\|=$$
$$\left\|\frac {x+\delta v+\|x\|x+\|x\|\delta v-x-\|x +\delta v\|x}{(1 +\|x+\delta v\|)(1+\|x\|)}\right\|=$$
$$\left\|\frac{\delta(1+\|x\|)v+(\|x\|-\|x+\delta v\|)x}{(1 +\|x+\delta v\|)(1+\|x\|)} \right\|$$
now remember $x+\delta v$ is just a point $\delta$ away from $x$, so their norms are at maximum $\delta$ apart  The denominator is bigger than one so we can get rid of it and still have an upper bound, this lets us simplify the entire mess to
$$\|f(x+\delta v)-f(x)\|\leq \|\delta(1+\|x\|)v+\delta x\|\leq \delta (\|(1+\|x\|))v\|+\|x\|)$$
the latter split by the triangle inqequality
Since $v$ is a unit vector, this further simplifies to

$$\|f(x+\delta v)-f(x)\|\leq \delta (1 + 2\|x\|)$$

Since $|x|$ is a constant (it was just the preimage of $y$),  you can bound this to be less than $\epsilon$ by making $$\delta < \frac \epsilon {1 + 2\|x\|}$$

Note this is a generally useful way of representing points close to a vector as being that vector plus the distance times a unit vector indicating the direction.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the comment of @TheoBendit, you can prove that $x\mapsto 1 + \|x\|$ and $x\mapsto x$ are continuous, from whence it results that $f$ is continuous (why?).

Indeed, this is the case. Let us prove the first claim first. In order to do so, we shall prove the norm is continuous. We shall start with arguing that $|\|x\| - \|a\|| \leq \|x - a\|$. In fact, one has that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\|x\| = \|(x + y) - y\| \leq \|x + y\| + \|y\|\\\\
\|y\| = \|(x + y) - x\| \leq \|x + y\| + \|x\|
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

which implies that
\begin{align*}
\begin{cases}
\|x + y\| \geq \|x\| - \|y\|\\\\
\|x + y\| \geq \|y\| - \|x\|
\end{cases}
\end{align*}
whence we conclude that $\|x + y\|\geq\max\{\|x\| - \|y\|,\|y\| - \|x\|\} = |\|x\| - \|y\|| $.

Particularly, if we set that $y = -a$, the desired claim holds.

Consequently, for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ there corresponds $\delta_{\varepsilon} = \varepsilon$ such that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ it results that
\begin{align*}
\|x - a\| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow |\|x\| - \|a\|| < \|x - a\| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
and we are done. Since constant functions are continuous (why?) and the sum of continuous functions is continuous (why?), we conclude the function $x\mapsto 1 + \|x\|$ is continuous.

Based on a similar argument, it is possible to prove the identity function is continuous as follows: for every $\varepsilon\in\mathbb{R}_{>0}$ there corresponds $\delta_{\varepsilon} = \varepsilon$ such that for every $x\in\mathbb{R}^{2}$ it results that
\begin{align*}
\|x - a\| < \delta_{\varepsilon} \Rightarrow \|\text{Id}(x) - \text{Id}(a)\| = \|x - a\| < \varepsilon
\end{align*}
and we are done. Gathering all the previous results, the proposed claim is true.

Hopefully this helps!